# Macro for searching for text in a different sheet, finding column, and copy/pasting into original sheet

Tags: excel, macros, copy

I'm trying to make a code that will look at text that you've typed in A1 of Sheet 2 (let's call it "zap") and search for it in row 1 of Sheet 1.

When it finds the specific column of row 1 where there is also a cell labeled "zap" then it copies that entire column into Column B in Sheet 2.

I'm pretty new to writing Macros, but have worked with MATLAB, cogent, a little Java, and am hoping to learn new stuff!  Thanks ahead of time for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s2 As Worksheet, s1 As Worksheet

    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set r = s1.Range("1:1").Find(What:=s2.Range("A1").Value, After:=s1.Range("A1"))
    r.EntireColumn.Copy s2.Range("B1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for such a prompt and helpful answer!